# Parse Issue, @end must appear in context

Tags: xcode, parsing

I am trying to build this app and every time I try to build it, it always gives me a parse error.

```
#import "XYZFlipsideViewController.h"

@end  <===This is the error.  It says: '@end' must appear in an Objective-C context

@interface XYZMainViewController : UIViewController <XYZFlipsideViewControllerDelegate,     
UIPopoverControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *viewWeb;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *flipsidePopoverController;

@end
```

I have tried to delete the first

```
@end
```

but it always gives me a lot more errors.

Comment: The first one doesn't belong there. What errors do you get after deleting it?

Comment: Cannot find interface declaration, property implementation must have its declaration, cannot use 'super' because of its root class, use of undeclared identifier, property 'flipsidePopoverController' not found, with a few of those repeated.

Comment: Are you defining an interface in a `.m` file? You generally want to do that in the header (`.h`) file.

Comment: The error is in a .h file.

Comment: Definitely get rid of the leading `@end`. But for this .h file of yours, you need a `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` line before your `@interface` (or in your `.pch` file) at the very least. You probably also want `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` in your `.pch` file, too, or else you might get errors on the `NS` classes.